# Change default of Android Studio build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, jcenter

Currently, when I create a new Android Studio project, the project build.gradle file looks like so (in part):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
```

Because I'm behind a firewall, I have to manually change it to this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
```

Not a big deal, but is there a way to have Android Studio do this by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably change the default template at the path:

`<android-studio>/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidProject/root/build.gradle.ftl`

Comment: I have to open the file as administrator so as to get write privileges, but other than that, no problems.